# How to write `lsb-release` again on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lts, lsb-release

I had to edit `lsb-release` to make the Intel 1.0.7 graphics installer work on my Ubuntu 14.04 following [this article](http://dan.bodar.com/2015/01/13/intel-graphics-installer-on-ubuntu-14-10/) (this is for Ubuntu 14.10, but also suitable to Ubuntu 14.04). However, I forgot to run:

```
sudo cp /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release.backup
```

and I accidentally deleted everything in the `lsb-release` file.

I cannot reinstall `base-files` as suggested in a comment:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall base-files
dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The following also returns the same error as above:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lsb-release
```

How can I write this text file again?

Answer (score 2):

For those who visit this now, these are the contents for Ubuntu 20.04.1:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
```

Edit these according to your version.